# Coding in VSCode Python 3.6, input doesn't show out put

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

i'm just getting into programming and i've installed VScode and i've been using python 3.6. When i enter a simple code like:

```
    print("Hello world!")
    NAME = input("What's your name?")
    print(NAME)
```

And when i run debug it appears the print Hello world! and the input "What's your name?" and i type whatever, and it doesn't print the NAME afterward.
Thank you in advance for the time taken to answer me.

Answer (score 1):

please use IntegratedTerminal ratherthan internalTerminal
Maybe you can see it:
https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Capture-User-Input-via-input()-or-raw_input()